# Can a clip-path(ed) image be resized to fill the parent width

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with a 'letter-box' sized header image.
It looks fine on large screens, but on small-width mobiles - it appears full-width, but only ~100px deep and thus looks small and indistinct.

I could have two seperate images:

- letter-box - for wide screens
- 3x4 - for narrow screens

Or with css I could:

```
clip-path inset(0 0 300px 0)
```

and remove the right-hand portion of the image - to make it 3x4

But how could I 'resize' the reduced image to 100% width?

I've tried:
object-fit: fill/cover/contain/etc.

but they don't seem to do what I want.

Comment: where your code?

Comment: It's WordPress 'GridBulletin' template, so I don't have access to change the code, but we have the  'scripts n styles' app.  so I can add javascript & CSS to change/add.

Comment: Then you need to look at how your code is located in WordPress. I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

After more testing it seems that:

```
clip-path: inset( 0 300px 0 0) !important;  // to clip-out the right-hand side of the image
```

and

```
width: 125% !important;    // to enlarge the reduced image so it fills the width
overflow: hidden !important; // not sure if needed?
```

do work together (in a @media rule) to accomplish a single image for wide & mobile devices.

Also needed:

```
max-width: none;  // as the the t'plate has default of 100%
```

=====
Mixed 'px' and '%'s above over-complicate.  So eventually went with:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px ) {
    /* nb.  inset(top, left, bottom, right )  */
 .header-img { 
    clip-path: inset(0 27% 0 0) !important;   /* to clip-off the right-hand side of the image */
    width: calc( 136.9% - 20px ) !important;    /* to enlarge the reduced image so it fills the width */
/*  20px above is the right margin */
    overflow: hidden !important; /* not sure if needed?  */
    max-width: inherit;
    }
}
```